# How to convert srcset links from https to http?

Tags: database, https, images, http

After trying SSL and having some unfortunate problem with it, I decide to go back to HTTP. Everything seems find, by the `srcset` attribute of `<img>` tag is still https everywhere.

This post [Wordpress: srcset gets HTTP instead of HTTPS in all posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461058/3416774) asks for the opposite direction, but still provides me guides to diagnose. However:

1. In `wp-includes > media.php`, I can find the `wp_calculate_image_srcset` method, but unable to find these two lines:

   ```
   $image_baseurl = _wp_upload_dir_baseurl();
   $image_baseurl = trailingslashit( $image_baseurl ) . $dirname;
   ```
2. In `wp_options` table, both `home` and `siteurl` already have http values.

I also delete all cache. Still no help.

What else do I need to check? Here is my page: [quảcầu.com](http://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/).

Comment: Those srcset images are coming from Jetpack. So you need to turn off Photon from Jetpack to serve images on HTTP and from your own server. Not sure why would you revert all of this, when you might end up adding https all over again.

Comment: thanks. If you make that an answer I'll accept it. Anyway, I wonder what is the point of that feature, if all it does is change the link from HTTP to HTTPS. And the reason I do that is because my server somehow blocking access of Facebook bot. See [What makes Open Graph checkers unable to detect Open Graph data? - Let's Encrypt Community Support](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/what-makes-open-graph-checkers-unable-to-detect-open-graph-data/100261?u=ooker)

Comment: I'll post it as answer and about your other question I'd need to go through it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ooker It's the Jetpack that is serving you the images on https. If you'd turn off the Photon add-on from Jetpack you should be able to get images served over http from your own server.

Also if you turn off Photon, images won't be served from CDN anymore, so you might have to figure that out.